# Get total number of non-blank lines from text file?

Tags: c#, readlines

I am using...

```
File.ReadLines(@"file.txt").Count();
```

...to find the total number of lines in the file. How can I do this, but ignore all blank lines?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method with `Count`:

```
File.ReadLines(@"file.txt").Count(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));
```

Or another way with `All` and `char.IsWhiteSpace`:

```
File.ReadLines(@"file.txt").Count(line => !line.All(char.IsWhiteSpace));
```

Comment: just as a variety, also `line.Trim() != String.Empty` would work, though probably not the best option.